# How to transform feature matrix using Matlab's LDA (fitcdiscr)

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, feature-detection, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I want to get LDA (Linear Discriminant Analysis) matrix (actually the eigenvector of separability matrix) and use it as a feature transform in my code or simply as **Dimension Reduction**. I've to use Matlab to be consistent with built-in cross validation method.

So far I've found two other implementation which do what I want regarding the projection (but not the cross validation). One is [Dwinell's](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29673-lda--linear-discriminant-analysis) implementation and the other is [Yarpiz](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/53151-linear-discriminant-analysis--lda--aka-fisher-discriminant-analysis--fda-) but I coulnd't use the same technique with matlab built-in function (fitcdiscr). It seems that this function implements both LDA and QDA but reading the help, I couldn't find the approperiate matrix in the model.

Here is my test script to use these 3 implementation:

```
clear all
load fisheriris.mat
label = convertCat2Ind(species)

[fMat1, wk, lambda] = LDA_Kalami(meas, label);
% fMat1(:, 1:3) is the new projected feature matrix

wd = lda_dwinnell(meas, label);
fMat2DW = [ones(size(meas, 1), 1), meas] * wd.';
% fMat2DW(:, 1:3) is the projected feature matrix

Mdl = fitcdiscr(meas,species);
% What is the same projection matrix?
% Mdl.X is the original meas, and 
% meas * Mdl.Sigma isn't that projection matrix to reduce meas dimensionality
```

My question is how to extract/compute the eig(sb) (the projection matrix) with matlab built-in function just like the above lda implementations?